# If the class "makes"

Tags: single-word-requests, idioms

At the college where I teach, a class might be canceled if too few students sign up for it. We say the class didn't "make".

"I'll be teaching that class in the spring... if it makes."

Is there a better way of putting it? Common use, intransitive verb, active voice, preferably a single word?

Comment: I'll be teaching that class in the spring assuming adequate enrolment. Your sentence has a verb; that is "will be teaching".

Comment: I've never heard this usage before. Is it an abbreviated form of "make quota?"

Comment: Are you sure the phrase isn't "make **it**? That's a pretty common expression to mean "to achieve a goal or be successful," as in "I didn't think I'd finish that race, but I made it." It seems this would fit the context you describe: "I'll be teaching that class if it makes it."

Comment: .......... runs

Comment: If I really wanted to be clear I would say "if the class achieves the minimum enrollment cutoff," or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make it explicit?

> I'll be teaching that class in the spring, if it exists.

If the reason is not implied:

> I'll be teaching that class in the spring, if there is adequate enrollment. -- Eilliott Frisch

Answer (score 0):

I would say you will be teaching the class if it (the roster) ***fills***.